# How to apply complicated random formula n-th time?

Tags: google-sheets, random, google-sheets-formula

I have a big spreadsheet with a lot of data and formula, in F19 is a random value which is built from all these data and formula.
I would like to get a sample of N=30 values that are given by this formula.
Of course I could copy paste the number, refresh the sheet, recopy paste etc N times, but let's be smart here. Is there a way to do so?

I have tried using `ARRAYFORMULA()` but not sure how to use it to get a sample of N values from the F19 cell.

Comment: Can you share a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that the community can use to see what you'd like to do? Like a dummy sheet so we can visualize and replicate what you have. You may include your desired output in it as well.